# Simple dotfiles install in zsh

Tags: zsh

How do I symlink all dotfiles on a dir to my home dir using zsh? i.e. I have a dir with `.gitconfig` in it, and I'd like to symlink it to `~/.gitconfig`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sym-links at your local dir to your home dir:

```
cd my-own-local-dir
for ifile in .*(.); do    # notice the '(.)' matching only normal files 
   # rm -fv $ifile        # COMMENTED OUT, removing the original...
   ln -vs ~/$ifile $ifile # sym-links to your home dir...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try [dotbot](https://github.com/anishathalye/dotbot). It supports to manage dotfiles by using a `yaml` file. Easy for mapping :D

For example:

```
- link:
~/.config/terminator:
  create: true
  path: config/terminator
~/.vim: vim
~/.vimrc:
  relink: true
  path: vimrc
~/.zshrc:
  force: true
  path: zshrc
```